# Node invisible - can't find specific node, not even by grep?

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

is there a way to find a node that is marked erroneous by roswtf? I can't find any mention of it using grep or any other text finder. Even if I grep across the whole hard disk. It appears totally invisible but still existing for rosgraph and roswtf.

I don't need it. How can I find its location and get rid of it?

Thanks

Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10048/node-invisible---can%27t-find-specific-node,-not-even-by-grep?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2011-05-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-05-24**:
can you please provide more details, such as the output from roswtf that you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nodes that crash can leave behind stale registration information.  In general, it doesn't notably effect your system to have this stale registration information around.  If it really bothers you, you can run:

```
rosnode cleanup
```

which will purge all registration information for nodes that cannot be verified.  NOTE: running this in a wifi/lossy connection setup could remove nodes that are still valid.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1